# Python data Frame get all permutations in same column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, permutation

I have a python data frame containing list of words.

```
Column Name
 1. text1  
 2. text2
 3. text3
```

I need to find all permutations from the data frame with 3 words at a time in a single column seperated by space. The output has to look like below.

```
    text1 text2 text3
    text1 text3 text2 
    text2 text3 text1
    text2 text1 text3
    text3 text2 text1
    text3 text1 text2
```

Any help on this is appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is great for this! Specifically, [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
import itertools as it

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']})
perms = it.permutations(df.col)
```

This gives you a generator, `perms`, that will give you the next permutation every time you call `next(perms)`, something that things like `for perm in perms:` or `[perm for perm in perms]` does automatically.

Note that if you have more than three elements in your dataframe, but only want permutations of three at a time, you would use `it.permutations(df.col, 3)` in the above. Also note that you will get a TON of permutations if you have a lot of elements in your dataframe. It's the binomial "number of permutations equals n choose k", or `N = n! / (k! * (n - k)!)`.

You can get the output format you want with something like:

```
result = '\n'.join([' '.join([s for s in perm]) for perm in perms])
print(result)

text1 text2 text3
text1 text3 text2
text2 text1 text3
text2 text3 text1
text3 text1 text2
text3 text2 text1
```

Comment: @jpp right! I always forget I can just use `list` to unpack an iterator. Updated.

Comment: I will try this. I need the out put in a single column with words seperated by spaces. I have updated my question(Missed to add it while writing te question). Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @Ajith gotcha, updated my answer with a way to get the output format that you want. If you want this in a column of your dataframe, you can just do `df['new_col'] = result`.

Comment: I tried list1=list(it.permutations(words.a,3)). But is getting MemoryError. The data frame has more than 2000 records.

Comment: So you have to consider whether what you want to do is feasible. Say you have 2000 items in your dataframe, and you want all permutations of any 3 of those items in a list. That is "2000 choose 3" permutations, which is `2000! / (3! * (2000 - 3)!) = 1331334000` permutations! You will probably run out of memory with a billion permutations.

Comment: That said, if you just want something that can generate those permutations, `perms = it.permutations(words.a, 3)` should do the trick. This creates a generator that gives you the next permutation each time you call `next(perms)`, which things like `for perm in perms:` does automatically. The part that's causing you to run out of memory is actually unpacking a billion permutations into a list.